# LWC Lightning Record Form Submits on Enter in Input Field

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

This may be default behavior, but I'm having an issue with using the [Lightning Record Form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form). Basically, if the user is inputting data into a field and presses enter the form will submit. I don't see an easy way to prevent without losing enter key functionality by preventing default (tabbing and selecting a date for instance).

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want your user to be able to submit the form using the Enter key, you're inevitably going to lose the functionality.

Comment: Well, the issue is when the hit enter in the field they are filling out. Let's say then type in text in the field and hit enter the form will submit. They don't want that to happen. They want it only to submit when they click the Save button or tab to it and then press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Did `preventDefault()` not help?

```
export default class RecordFormEditExample extends LightningElement {

    handleSubmit(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) event.preventDefault();
     }
}
```

If you need enter to work on the button, combine this with `onclick` event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only issue there is that users would not be able to submit the form if they tab to the Save button and hit enter. I will need to do some testing.